# Internet TV streaming applications

Tags: software-recommendation, streaming

Are there any programs for Ubuntu that can pull TV streams from the Internet?  I have in mind programs that work like the apps that come installed on blu-ray players — BBC iPlayer, Hulu and/or YouTube.

I know XMBC can but it's too fiddly and resource-hungry, I just want "net TV" apps and not a full media center. Boxee was great for this; it was a media center but it had an interface for the apps and didn't just stick them in some strange menu as XBMC does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if this will fit your exact needs, but I use Miro to stay up to date with all my podcasts and rss feeds that I like to watch.  We all know Netflix doesn't work on Linux so it doesn't support that, but Amazon Prime is similar to Netflix and doesn't have ads like Hulu which is the only reason I don't like Hulu.  If you pay for something you shouldn't have ads, but back on topic.

Miro is probably the best application for searching new shows and staying up to date.  It does have a bunch of channels like youtube, hulu, pbs, and you can add more if you like.

[image: download for ubuntu]

Hope this helps.

Comment: This looks good could be what I need thaks

Answer (score 4):

As `miro` has been suggested as a good general application (and `minitube` could alternatively be used for youtube videos), a particularly useful program for UK users like Mark is in the Ubuntu repositories and is called `get-iplayer`.

**Note**: anyone in the world can listen to all the **radio** output from the bbc via the bbc site, but currently tv is limited to UK users, but as Mark is in the UK I thought this answer might be useful. With `get-iplayer` you can stream content to `vlc` or record it to disk. More information is available [here at the linuxcentre](http://linuxcentre.net/getiplayer).
(If someone can confirm whether the radio (not tv) using `get-iplayer` works outside the UK I would be interested.)

```
sudo apt-get install get-iplayer
```

Then run the command `get_iplayer` in terminal to get the tv lists and `get_iplayer --help` for a list of options.
If you want to get the radio lists instead enter `get_iplayer --type radio`.

When you update the tv lists with `get_iplayer` (without any options), you will be presented with a large amount of numbered items, but you can search it, for example, like this:

```
get_iplayer search gardening
```

An example of a way to stream tv to vlc (you choose the stream number from the list generated by `get-iplayer`):

```
get_iplayer --stream 895 --modes=flashvhigh --player="vlc - "
```

A way to record a program (you have to choose the number of the program after you run `get_iplayer` to generate the list):

```
get_iplayer 288 --modes=flashvhigh --get
```

It is supposed to be possible to view live bbc tv channels through `get_iplayer`, but I have always had errors and returned to using the website. `Get_iplayer` is a very useful program nevertheless.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Directly from this [link](http://www.junauza.com/2012/06/how-to-watch-free-tv-shows-on-ubuntu.html) are 2 good options:

---

**Tv Maxe**

To install it, open Terminal (Ctrl + Alt + T) and paste this code:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:venerix/blug
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tv-maxe
```

---

**SopCast Player**

To install it, open Terminal (Ctrl + Alt + T) and paste this code:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/sopcast
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sopcast-player
```

---

**Note**: Both TV maxe and SopCast Player use P2P (peer-to-peer networking) to stream their content. Though these services are not illegal per se, watching paid TV channels or any licensed ones might get you in trouble depending on your country's jurisdiction. Please keep this mind before trying any of these options out.

See [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/use-sopcast-to-get-real-time-streaming-with-tv-maxe-linux/) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P2PTV) for more information on this topic.

---

I was actually trying myself to find a nice application I was using on Ubuntu 12.10 just a few weeks ago. I can't remember its name at the moment: I only remember a red icon and the possibility to filter TV Channels by country. I believe it is not present on Ubuntu 12.04 Software Centre, but I might be wrong. Any suggestions welcome...I really liked that one!

EDIT -> Guess I found it! It's called **FreetuxTV** and here's how to install it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:freetuxtv/freetuxtv
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install freetuxtv
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated its formatting and added a paragraph on the legality of using these services.

Answer (score 0):

Lets not forget XBMC, in addition to it's common use as a local file player, it has many streaming feeds built in.